# What is $(\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z)/k(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)$?

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers

When $p$ is prime and $k\in \Bbb N$ such that $p$ does not divide $k$, is it always true that $(\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z)/k(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)=\{e\}$?

Comment: Hint: a nonzero element $k$ in a field $F$ is a unit so $\,kF = F,\,$ i.e. $\,(k) = (1).\ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.** The statement
$$ (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}) / k(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}) = \{e\} $$
is equivalent to
$$ k(\mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z}) = (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}) .$$
To prove that $k(\mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z}) = (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, it suffices to show that $[1] \in k(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ (do you see why?).
Now by your assumptions, $k$ and $p$ are coprime. This means that
$$ 1 = a k + b p $$
for some integers $a,b$ ([Bézout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)). Can you now see why $[1] \in k(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: Thanks!!! So the map $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z, 1\mapsto k$ is an isomorphism, yes? @DaanMichels

Comment: @MyNameIs - Yes, it is an isomorphism of groups.